# Android - CardView contents not being displayed

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-cardview, cardview

I am trying to create three `CardView`, with each of them containing some `ImageView` and `TextView`. I am not using `RecyclerView`as I will always have these 3 `CardViews` in that activity. But why are the contents of the `CardView`such as the texts being displayed (both in Preview and the app) ?

This is what I get:
[image]

Here is my XML code for the activity. I have set the corresponding values in `strings.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.yankee.cw.ll_home">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/card_view0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="24dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/ll_home_card_title_1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/ll_home_card_content_1"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/ll_home_card_title_2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/ll_home_card_content_2"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.70"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/ll_home_card_title_3"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/ll_home_card_content_3"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Set linear layout and textview height  android:layout_height="0dp" to wrap content.

Comment: Try changing the scrollview to a nestedscrollview, also you can remove the linear layout around the card view , you can achieve padding, margin without it

Comment: @KevinCrain Thanks, ok, I'll try that.

Comment: @KevinCrain I am getting an error that `ScrollView` can host only one direct child. That's why I put it in a `LinearLayout` first.

Comment: @Yankee Don't remove the linear just change to nested scroll view, sorry I scrolled two fast and thought theres was only one cardview, now I see there is more.

Comment: @KevinCrain I get the same behavior using `ScrollView` and `NestedScrollView` except that I see the preview of the whole screen in Preview pane of Android Studio when I use `NestedScrollView` and just the preview of the three cards when using `ScrollView`. Thanks a lot for the information, though.

Comment: @Yankee Anytime, next time I will physically test the code before giving a suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set height in LinearLayout to match_parent, not 0dp,
and also the last TextView in each CardView is set to 0 height, so you should change it, you can use weights inside LinearLayout but not on it (unless it is inside other linearlayout)

Comment: Thanks for the info on usage of weights inside LinearLayout.